# What's the most effective way of storing this data?

Tags: database, database-design, parse-platform

Need help figuring out a good way to store data effectively and efficiently

I'm using Parse (JavaScript SDK), here's an example of what I'm trying to store

Predictions of football (soccer) matches so an example of one match would be;

> Team A v Team B
>
> EventID = "abc"
>
> Categories = ["League-1","Sunday-League"]
>
> User123 predicts the score will be Team A 2-0 Team B -> so 2-0
>
> User456 predicts the score will be Team A 1-3 Team B -> so 1-3

Each event has information attached to it like an eventId, several categories, start time, end time, a result and more

I need to record a score prediction per user for each event (usually 10 events at a time so a lot of predictions will be coming in)

I need to store these so I can cross reference the correct result against the user's prediction and award points based on their prediction, the teams in the match and the categories of the event but instead of adding to a total I need all the awarded points stored separately per category and per user so I can then filter based on predictions between set dates and certain categories e.g.

> Team A v Team B
>
> EventID = "abc"
>
> Categories = ["League-1","Sunday-League"]
>
> User123 prediction = 2-0
>
> Actual result = 2-0

So now I need to award X points to User123 for Team A, Team B, "League-1", and "Sunday-League" and record it to the event date too.

Comment: Why store points at all? You have the prediction and the result. So you can always calculate the points on the fly. Even apply another points algorithm whenever you want.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - Yeah I could do that, I think I glazed over that thinking it would take up too much time doing that every time for every user (in a leaderboard scenario especially) but maybe I'm wrong - changing the points algorithm would be very easy your way. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a table for games and a table for users and then an associative table to handle the many to many relationship. This is a pretty standard many to many relationship.